# How can I make Remember Me more secured

Tags: php, session, cookies, passwords

I'm trying to do "Remember Me" on my website and have added the code below to my login script.

The password is run through sha1() function and the username was trimmed and run through mysql_real_escape_string() before assigning it to a SESSION.

How can I make this more secured, against hijacking.

Thanks.

```
if($_POST['remember']) {
    setcookie("CookieUser", $_SESSION['usrename'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24      100, "/");
    setcookie("CookiePass", $_SESSION['password'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24       100);
}
```

Comment: you can use `base64_decode()` and `base64_encode()` function in php

Comment: One way to make it more secure from hijacking/hackers is to _not_ put passwords in cookies. Like KoolKabin says, use tokens of various "factors" or salts of complicated algorithms and use those instead.

Comment: You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for remember me, we use token setting. When user logins to the system with username and password a **token** is generated in database with respective username, ip and other factors. I use the same token and username for saving as cookies and when user returns with token, and username from cookie, we verify the token with specified ip, username and other factors again and set the user logged in status if matches all.

this way i skip storing password in cookie and is somewhat secure one.

Comment: thank you for your answer... But how can I make use of the token? Can you please give an example of how to implement these thank you.